# Excel-how to convert multiple rows into a single row for each unique identifier in column A

Tags: excel-formula

I have a large data set(over 1 million rows) of patient names, problems/diagnoses, and the dates these diagnoses were entered(with each variable as a column header).

I would like to pull data from this source file to add to an existing file which has about 900 unique patient names with other demographics(in columns).

I am not able to use the vlookup function because most patients have multiple problems.

Are there any other functions or tricks which might be helpful?

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

Sample of what Data Currently looks like:

```
Name     Diagnosis    Date of Dx
A        Head         11/15/12
B        Leg          09/08/14
B        Elbow        10/11/15
C        Hand         02/23/16
A        Toe          04/11/13
A        Eye          05/25/15
C        Ear          12/21/14
```

What I would like Data Set to Look like:

```
Name   Dx#1   Date#1    Dx#2   Date#2    Dx#3   Date#3   
A      Head   11/15/12  Toe    04/11/13  Eye    05/25/15
B      Leg    09/08/14  Elbow  10/11/15  n/a    n/a
C      Hand   02/23/16  Ear    12/21/14  n/a    n/a
```

Comment: I understand confidentiality but could you mock up some data and expected outcome and post it in your original post with edit.  That being said with 1 million data points, VBA is going to be your best bet.

Comment: I agree with Scott. Please provide a sample of both tables and especially one of your desired outcome - there is an 1:n relationship between patient and problems, so are you looking to aggregate over problems?

Comment: would you consider using google sheets instead of excel? You could then use Filter() and Join() to achieve what you describe...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to paste a table into my question so that it formats appropriately.  Yesterday I tried unsuccessfully to paste an image.  Today I tried typing a table in but it is formatted into jumble.

Comment: I don't think I want to aggregate.  Each patient has an unknown number of diagnoses, I would like to set up my spread sheet so that the problems could be listed out distinctly (prob #1, date of prob #1, prob #2, date of prob #2, etc.).

Comment: Ideally all of the data gets to stay in one Excel spreadsheet.  There is pre-existing patient demographics that has already been pulled and is waiting in an Excel spreadsheet.  Plus, I have never done anything with a Google sheet.  Do you have a good starting point link for those who have never manipulated Google sheets before?  If there turns out to be no easy route to doing this in Excel, Google sheets would certainly be better than nothing.

Comment: Looks like VA firewall does not allow Google docs.  Forgot to mention I work for Veteran Affairs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're familiar with the index and match functions, but you can use those to create the sheet. The easiest way would be to add several helper columns (in your example 3) and use the match function to get the reference row that you want.

From there you can offset the search range by previous match to find the next match. You can do this as many times as necessary depending on the number of conditions a patient has.

After that it's a simple index function to fill in the rows of the table with the desired values. You can clean up the extra cells with iferror if you want.

Assuming your data is in columns A1:C8, and your output dataset is in columns E1:K4, the following formulas will give you the desired output. The helper columns are found in L1:N4. These formulas would go in row 2, but you can drag them down to calculate for the rest of the rows.

I'll add the column above each formula:

**E**
No formula, list all patient names

**F**
    =INDEX(B:B,L2)

**G**
    =INDEX(C:C,L2)

**H**
    =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,M2),"")

**I**
    =IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,M2),"")

**J**
    =IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,N2),"")

**K**
    =IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,N2),"")

**L**
    =MATCH(E2,$A$1:$A$8,0)

**M**
    =IFERROR(MATCH($E2,OFFSET($A$1,L2,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-L2),0)+L2,"")

**N**
    =IFERROR(MATCH($E2,OFFSET($A$1,M2,0,COUNTA($A:$A)-M2),0)+M2,"")

Hope this helps, and let me know if you have any questions about the formulas.

Comment: That's brilliant, Ben!  Thank you.  Just tried it and it does what I was hoping to do.